# Solve recurrence T(n) = T(6n/5) + 1

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity, recurrence, master-theorem

So I'm preparing for the Algorithms exam and I don't know how to solve this recurrence `T(n) = T(6n/5) + 1` since `b = 5/6 < 1` and Master theorem cannot be applied.
I hope that someone can give me a hint on how to solve this. :)

Comment: By the way, consider posting on CS instead, since you are not asking about concrete code: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165519/where-should-i-post-questions-about-algorithms-stack-overflow-or-software-engin

Comment: @Mörre Thanks for the suggestion, I'll keep that in mind

Comment: @hnefatl Yep:) thanks for the explanation:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given just that recurrence relation (and no additional information like `T(x) = 1` when `x > 100`), an algorithm with time complexity as described by the relation will never terminate, as the amount of work increases at each call.

```
T(n) = T(6n/5) + 1
     = T(36n/25) + 2
     = T(216n/125) + 3
     = ...
```

You can see that the amount of work increases each call, and that it's not going to have a limit as to how much it increases by. As a result, **there is no bound on the time complexity** of the function.

---

We can even (informally) argue that such an algorithm cannot exist - increasing the size of the input by `1.2` times each call requires at least `0.2n` work, which is clearly `O(n)` - but the actual cost at each step is claimed to be `1`, `O(1)`, so it's impossible for an algorithm described by
this exact recurrence to exist (but fine for algorithms with recurrence eg. `T(n) = T(6n/5) + n`).

Comment: Oh, I've noticed that, but since professor said to solve the recurrence, I assumed there was some boundary._.
Thanks for your help!